# Proper way to handle exception when function returns None

Tags: python, exception

What's the best way to handle a case where a function returns None. For example:

```
def my_function():
     if <some_stuff_works>:
         return <stuff>
     else:
         return None

my_var = my_function()
```

What I'd like to do is raise an exception if my_var is None and then set to a certain value. So something like:

```
try:
    my_var = my_function()
except ValueIsEmpty:
    my_var = "EMPTY"
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Why not return "EMPTY" instead of None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the function, there's no need to come up with a creative exception: just check if it is `None` and give it an appropriate value.

```
my_var = my_function()
if my_var is None:
    my_var = 'default_value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're want to use exceptions, try this;

```
def my_function():
     if <some_stuff_works>:
         return <stuff>
     raise ValueError

try:
    my_var = my_function()
except ValueError:
    my_var = "EMPTY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var = my_function() or 'default_value'
```

But, `var` will be equal to 'default_value' when `my_function` returns

- `None` (what you want)
- `False`
- `0`
- empty list `[]` (thanks to @roganjosh)

Up to you to choose what you want. If you don't what this, @brianpck's answer's still the best one.

You also make the function raise an exception instead of returning `None`.

```
def my_function():
    if <some_stuff_works>:
        return <stuff>
    else:
        raise SomeException # maybe TypeError, whatever
```

And then call it like this:

```
try:
    result = my_function()
except SomeException:
    result = 'EMPTY'
```

Or even better:

```
def my_function():
    if <some_stuff_works>:
        return <stuff>
    # no need for the else because return end up the function execution.
    # so if it returns <stuff>, it will stop, and not look further
    return 'EMPTY'
```

Comment: Also empty lists etc. will return `default_value` since they are falsey too.